# Is it possible in CUDA to start a kernel in stream A between two events in stream B?

Tags: cuda

I have two streams A and B in separate contexts (different devices, different host threads, created automatically). I need to synchronise an execution of a kernel K in stream A with 2 different events in stream B, and so that K starts just after event 1 has been triggered but not event 2. Is it possible in principle? (using cudaStreamWaitEvent?)

My stream B contains a loop, so that I have a sequence of events like 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,etc. But my kernel K in separate stream should start only between 1 and 2 and not after 2 and before 1.

Example:

```
Host thread X:
Loop:
  kernel1(userStreamA)
  ...
  kernelK(userStreamA) <-- this should start only between E1 and E2
  ...
  kernelN(userStreamA)

Host thread Y: 
Loop:
  kernel1(userStreamB)
  record(E1)
  kernel2(userStreamB)
  some other kernels in userStreamB
  record(E2)
  kernel3(userStreamB)
  ...
  kernelN(userStreamB)
```

Comment: It's interesting that you refer to two different contexts yet also the cuda runtime API, for which the concept of a cuda context is largely hidden.  Are the two contexts created using the driver API?  Are you just using this nomenclature to refer to two separate devices, or are you creating 2 contexts on the same device?  If they are on the same device, wouldn't it be better not to do that? (look at the question you've just asked.)

Comment: on 2 different devices, created automatically by first setDevice invocation in two different host threads

Comment: Certainly arranging it so that kernel K in stream A does not begin until event1 in stream B has been recorded and triggered is easy. It's not entirely clear what you mean by "but not event 2". Do you mean that you do not want event 2 to be *recorded* until kernel K has been launched? The only way to ensure that event 2 in an asynchronous stream does not occur with respect to a kernel call in another stream, is to record the event in the stream that has the kernel call in it. Let's say event 1 has triggered and kernel K launched (the easy part). What behavior do you want *exactly* for event2?

Comment: I have added a pseudo-code example to the question description

Comment: I assume you're asking this question implicitly as "without any other form or knowledge of thread synchronization and without any additional knowledge about kernel execution time".  In that case, I'm not sure I can help.  If you're interested in some additional form of thread synchronization, then I can provide an example, that will still allow overlap/concurrency between the two streams.

Comment: kernelK execution time is comparable with E2-E1. I thought about cudaEventQuery or thread sync with mutexes; but I cannot estimate if is it possible at all. Do you mean it is possible with only additional host threads sync? Yes, I am interested in a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem I see (which you were getting at in your last question, probably) is that `cudaStreamWaitEvent` isn't useful if the event has not yet been "recorded".

Therefore to fix this, I propose adding a shared flag or semaphore between the two threads, which will ensure that `cudaStreamWaitEvent` in streamA does not get issued before the corresponding `cudaEventRecord` in streamB, and vice versa (we can use the same flag in this case).

The following code implements this using pthreads:

```
$ cat t884.cu
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N_LOOPS 3
#define MAX_EVENT  4
#define MAX_STREAM 4
#define PTHREADS 2

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

#define DELAY_T 1000000000ULL
template <int type>
__global__ void delay_kern(int i){

  unsigned long long time = clock64();
#ifdef DEBUG
  printf("hello %d\n", type);
#endif
  while (clock64() < time+(i*DELAY_T));
}

static int flag;

// The thread configuration structure.
typedef struct
{
    int device;
    int my_thread_ordinal;
    pthread_t thread;
    cudaError_t status;
    cudaStream_t *streams[MAX_STREAM];
    cudaEvent_t  *events[MAX_EVENT];
}
config_t;


// The function executed by each thread assigned with CUDA device.
void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    // Unpack the config structure.
    config_t *config = (config_t *)arg;

    int device = config->device;
    int my_thread=config->my_thread_ordinal;
    cudaError_t cuda_status = cudaSuccess;
    cuda_status = cudaSetDevice(device);
    if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set focus to device %d, status = %d\n",
            device, cuda_status);
        config->status = cuda_status;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }


    printf("thread %d initialized\n", my_thread);

    switch(config->my_thread_ordinal){
      case 0:
        //master thread - thread Y
        for (int i = 0; i < N_LOOPS; i++){
          delay_kern<0><<<1,1,0,*(config->streams[0])>>>(1);
          cudaEventRecord(*(config->events[0]), *(config->streams[0]));
          flag = 1;
          delay_kern<1><<<1,1,0,*(config->streams[0])>>>(1);
          while (flag == 1){};
          cudaStreamWaitEvent(*(config->streams[0]), *(config->events[2]),0);
          cudaEventRecord(*(config->events[1]), *(config->streams[0]));
          delay_kern<2><<<1,1,0,*(config->streams[0])>>>(1);
          }
        break;
      default:
        //slave thread - thread X
        for (int i = 0; i < N_LOOPS; i++){
          delay_kern<3><<<1,1,0,*(config->streams[1])>>>(1);
          while (flag == 0){};
          cudaStreamWaitEvent(*(config->streams[1]), *(config->events[0]),0);
          delay_kern<4><<<1,1,0,*(config->streams[1])>>>(1);
          cudaEventRecord(*(config->events[2]), *(config->streams[1]));
          flag = 0;
          delay_kern<5><<<1,1,0,*(config->streams[1])>>>(1);
          }
        break;
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("thread CUDA error");
    printf("thread %d complete\n", my_thread);
    config->status = cudaSuccess;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    flag = 0;
    const int nthreads = PTHREADS;

    // Create workers configs. Its data will be passed as
    // argument to thread_func.
    config_t* configs = (config_t*)malloc(sizeof(config_t) * nthreads);
    cudaStream_t s[MAX_STREAM];
    cudaEvent_t  e[MAX_EVENT];
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaStreamCreate(s+0);
    cudaEventCreate(e+0);
    cudaEventCreate(e+1);
    cudaSetDevice(1);
    cudaStreamCreate(s+1);
    cudaEventCreate(e+2);
    // create a separate thread
    // and execute the thread_func.
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        config_t *config = configs + i;
        config->device = i;
        config->my_thread_ordinal = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < PTHREADS; j++) config->streams[j] = s+j;
        for (int j = 0; j < PTHREADS+1; j++) config->events[j] = e+j;
        int status = pthread_create(&config->thread, NULL, thread_func, config);
        if (status) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create thread for device %d, status = %d\n",
                i, status);
        }
    }
    // Wait for device threads completion.
    // Check error status.
    int status = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        pthread_join(configs[i].thread, NULL);
        status += configs[i].status;
    }
    if (status)
        return status;

    free(configs);

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t884 t884.cu -lpthread
$ time ./t884
thread 1 initialized
thread 0 initialized
thread 1 complete
thread 0 complete

real    0m9.738s
user    0m12.102s
sys     0m6.235s
$
```

The kernel is templated so that we can differentiate things more easily in the profiler.  The kernel itself is designed to simply implement a delay of ~1s (this will be evident in the profiler output below).  Since each device is launching a total of 9 kernels, then we can crudely observe good overlap/concurrency simply by observing that the overall execution time is ~9s.   I have implemented a "3rd" event going "the other way" so as to ensure that the recording of event E2 in stream B does not occur until kernel K is complete. But to witness the specific synchrony you are looking for between kernel K in stream A and the events recorded in stream B, we need to look at this with the profiler:

```
$ nvprof --print-gpu-trace ./t884
==14914== NVPROF is profiling process 14914, command: ./t884
thread 0 initialized
thread 1 initialized
thread 1 complete
thread 0 complete
==14914== Profiling application: ./t884
==14914== Profiling result:
   Start  Duration            Grid Size      Block Size     Regs*    SSMem*    DSMem*      Size  Throughput           Device   Context    Stream  Name
887.60ms  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=0>(int) [188]
887.64ms  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=3>(int) [192]
1.86225s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=1>(int) [195]
1.86225s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=4>(int) [199]
2.81905s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=5>(int) [204]
2.83690s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=2>(int) [208]
3.77584s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=3>(int) [212]
3.81155s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=0>(int) [214]
4.78619s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=1>(int) [219]
4.78620s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=4>(int) [222]
5.74300s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=5>(int) [227]
5.76084s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=2>(int) [231]
6.69979s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=3>(int) [235]
6.73549s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=0>(int) [237]
7.71014s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=1>(int) [242]
7.71015s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=4>(int) [245]
8.66694s  956.79ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         8        0B        0B         -           -  GeForce GT 640          2        21  void delay_kern<int=5>(int) [250]
8.68479s  974.65ms              (1 1 1)         (1 1 1)         7        0B        0B         -           -  Quadro 5000 (0)         1        13  void delay_kern<int=2>(int) [254]

Regs: Number of registers used per CUDA thread. This number includes registers used internally by the CUDA driver and/or tools and can be more than what the compiler shows.
SSMem: Static shared memory allocated per CUDA block.
DSMem: Dynamic shared memory allocated per CUDA block.
$
```

What we witness in all 3 iterations of the loop, is that `delay_kern<int=1>` on one device and `delay_kern<int=4>`(effectively your Kernel K) on the other device have almost exactly the same start time.  This gives me pretty solid confidence that the event behavior is enforcing the desired behavior.

The thread synchronization imposed in this proposal has the drawback that we no longer can have a long blast of asynchronous activity issued by a host thread (although we still achieve processing concurrency on the devices, with the desired stream synchronization).  However, I don't really see a way to enforce your desired behavior without some element of thread synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, CUDA may not be the best option for using host concurrency calls to synchronize threads / processes in the way you require (i.e., with such fine grained control of specific host situations). If your question was limited to just using CUDA calls, then you can ignore the alternative solution given ahead.

You can easily achieve what you require with OpenMP or MPI, which will give you high level tools to control the CPU synchronization / execution flow of threads and processes, without compromising the GPU kernels at all.

Hint: consider OpenMP synchronization barriers or MPI wait/send/receive messages.

Comment: Well, here it's about device concurrency, not host concurrency.